# how to get all the ipv4 address in this content

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, ipv4

Would any body please tell me how to get all the ipv4 address(in the "()") in this content in bash in linux?

```
traceroute to 223.5.5.5 (223.5.5.5), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  1.2-88-23.rdns.scalabledns.com (23.88.2.1)  0.388 ms  0.404 ms  0.415 ms
 2  dist01-dc03-core.dc08.lax.ip4.scalabledns.com (172.246.0.235)  0.273 ms   18.825 ms  0.247 ms
 3  207.254.184.97 (207.254.184.97)  0.660 ms  0.771 ms  0.834 ms
 4  199.102.95.6 (199.102.95.6)  0.836 ms  0.808 ms  0.782 ms
 5  219.158.30.53 (219.158.30.53)  192.201 ms  192.186 ms  192.160 ms
 6  219.158.97.17 (219.158.97.17)  168.116 ms  168.193 ms  168.153 ms
 ....
```

The result should be like this

```
223.5.5.5
23.88.2.1
172.246.0.235
....
```

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this grep line works for your example:

```
grep -Po '.*\(\K[^)]*' file
```

It outputs:

```
223.5.5.5
23.88.2.1
172.246.0.235
207.254.184.97
199.102.95.6
219.158.30.53
219.158.97.17
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '\(\K[^)]+(?=\))' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
traceroute to 223.5.5.5 (223.5.5.5), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  1.2-88-23.rdns.scalabledns.com (23.88.2.1)  0.388 ms  0.404 ms  0.415 ms
 2  dist01-dc03-core.dc08.lax.ip4.scalabledns.com (172.246.0.235)  0.273 ms   18.825 ms  0.247 ms
 3  207.254.184.97 (207.254.184.97)  0.660 ms  0.771 ms  0.834 ms
 4  199.102.95.6 (199.102.95.6)  0.836 ms  0.808 ms  0.782 ms
 5  219.158.30.53 (219.158.30.53)  192.201 ms  192.186 ms  192.160 ms
 6  219.158.97.17 (219.158.97.17)  168.116 ms  168.193 ms  168.153 ms

$ grep -Po '\(\K[^)]+(?=\))' file.txt
223.5.5.5
23.88.2.1
172.246.0.235
207.254.184.97
199.102.95.6
219.158.30.53
219.158.97.17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\).*/\1/' file
223.5.5.5
23.88.2.1
172.246.0.235
207.254.184.97
199.102.95.6
219.158.30.53
219.158.97.17
```

Answer (score 0):

One line script in bash (basic knowledge in bash will be enough)
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

```
# while read l;do expr "$l" : ".*(\(.*\))";done <your_trc_file
223.5.5.5
23.88.2.1
172.246.0.235
207.254.184.97
199.102.95.6
219.158.30.53
219.158.97.17
```

More explanation:

```
# while read l;do echo "$l";done <file   ## read lines from a file

# # Matching with reg-exp by 'exp :' command
# expr "abcXdefghXXijk" : ".*X.*XX"      ## return length
11

# expr "abcXdefghXXijk" : ".*X\(.*\)XX"  ## return  extract 
defgh
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.